# Difference between command in an if statement and return value inspection

Tags: bash, return-value, if-statement

So I dunno how clever was that title but I was just thinking is it somehow "recommended" to use the second approach?:

The first approach:

```
if mv "$(ls -1 tarball* | head -1)" supertarball.tar; then
  echo "A Super Tarball created."
else
  echo "No tarballs here."
fi
```

The 2nd one (also assigning the `ls` string to a variable):

```
LAST="$(ls -1 tarball* | head -1)"
mv $LAST supertarball.tar
res=$?
if [ $res -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "A Super Tarball created."
else
  echo "No tarballs here."
fi
```

Comment: What is your question, "which one is better" or "what's the difference"? The first one is less code - if that answers both?

Comment: Well my question _is_ both. I just don't see many of those "first approaches" out there. That's why I was wondering, if it was a better practice to use the second one (eg. kinda like any of these: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both terrible, but to answer the basic question, use `if`. That's what it's for. Checking `$?` is only required if you need to branch by multiple possible nonzero statuses.

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf44

While you're reading, [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [always quote](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

```
f() {
    if [ -f "$1" ] && mv -- "$1" supertarball.tar; then
        echo 'A Super Tarball created.'
    else
        echo 'No tarballs here.'
    fi >&2
}

f tarball*
```

Comment: @desert69, sure, just waiting for a moment if there's any other ones.

Comment: Btw. What do you mean by always quoting? I thought that quoting the command of the variable was enough.

Comment: @Det The `"$LAST"` expansion to `mv` needs quoting in your second example. Ordinarily that would also be true of any expansions to `[`, though in this specific case you're able to guarantee the value. In fact, the place you have quoted is the one place it's not required (an assignment).

Comment: @ormaaj, hmm, yes, I can see that. Thank-you.